# Calculating $\int_{\partial B_8(1)} \frac{1}{1 - \cos(z)} \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Using the residue theorem we know that $$\int_{\partial B_8(1)}f(z) \ dz = 2\pi i \sum_{z_0 \text{ pole of } f \text{ inside }  B_8(1)} \mathrm{res}_{z_0}(f)$$ where $f(z) = \frac{1}{1- \cos(z)}$.
I tried calculating the residue for z = 0 by using taylor expansion $$\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)} = \frac{1}{1 - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}} = \frac{1}{ - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$ but got stuck here.

Comment: In order to avoid series expansions, use the residue formula $\displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}z^{n-1}}(z-z_0)^nf(z)$ for a $n^\mathrm{th}$-order pole $z_0$ of $f(z)$. Here you have a pole of order 2.

Comment: @Abezhiko How exactly did you calculate the order of the pole?

Comment: The order of the pole is evident from the first term in the series expansion of the denominator.$$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\mathcal O(z^6)\\\implies1-\cos(z)=\frac{z^2}2-\frac{z^4}{4!}+\mathcal O(z^6) = z^2 \left(\frac12 - \frac{z^2}{4!} + \mathcal O(z^4)\right)$$

Comment: $f(z)$ has two poles $z_0=0, z_1=2\pi$. So
$$\int_{\partial B_8(1)}f(z) \ dz = 2\pi i\bigg[\mathrm{Res}_{z_0}(f)+\mathrm{Res}_{z_1}(f)\bigg]=0. $$